# Looking for info on replacing MTB derailleur

Tags: mountain-bike, upgrade-or-new-bike

My previous derailleur went into my spokes and twisted up the hanger.

Bike is a early 2000s Minelli 7 speed.

How do I choose the best derailleur for rough off-road riding? I need one that won't budge too much since I plan trying jumps. I need something sturdy.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what your asking please?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Bicycles SX! Please take some time to look around this site to learn the rules about what questions are likely to be answered.

People manage to make it with all types of derailleurs just fine, even without any derailleurs, that is with internal gearing systems or even singlespeed. Have you considered compatibility with your bicycle, or do you do it the other way around: first buy a derailleur and then choose a bicycle that is compatible with it? As for jumps, you are not planning to land on the derailleur, right? It is not designated for it in any case.

Comment: What do u mean land on the derailleur?  And no i own a minelli or something along that spelling. Its a 21 speed. Looking at doing some upgrades just not sure where to start

Comment: A "sturdier" derailleur in a case of a crash will not only break itself but will also damage spokes, resulting in a broken rear wheel and an even more serious crash. In fact, not a single derailleur is qualified for surviving crashes, it is the task of the derailleur hanger to break first and save the much more expensive frame.

Comment: You could start with specifying exact name and brand of your bicycle and the model of derailleur. There are a lot of variables in the game. You should think about compatibility between derailleur and the rest of drivetrain first, not about its "sturdiness". It is no good to buy an expensive part that will not work with the rest of the drivetrain.

Comment: Ok thanks i dont know much about mtbs ive been more of a bmx person but body is too beat up from that now so been trying it out with mtbs and i like the landing and ride a heck of alot better

Comment: We don't give product recommendations but, anyway, I'm not really sure what you're looking for. "Road riding" and "trying jumps" sound like two completely different things, to me.

Comment: I dont have trails around me so i go around town looking for areas that i can do jumps or have a trickier ride

Comment: First thing to do is to get a spoke protector.  Yeah, the kids on the playground will laugh and point, but they DO help prevent the mess you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [Minelli web site](http://www.minelli-bikes.com/en/mountain.html) it seems their bikes are fairly inexpensive, using Acera, Altus and Alivio groupsets.

The latest Acera, Altus and Alivio groupsets are all 9 speed so I have to assume you have a slightly older bike when those groups came in 7 speeds, Or you might have a Tourney derailleur I guess.

Basically, you will just have to find a compatible 7 speed replacement derailleur. I'm afraid you don't have much choice in terms of 'sturdiness' as 7 speed drive-trains are now the lowest level, cheapest offerings. The good news is that a replacement will be inexpensive.

If you want to upgrade the bike, don't do it a component at a time, just buy a new or used better bike. There are plenty of answers to questions on this site that show how drivetrain component upgrades inevitably require replacing most or all of the drivetrain, and sometimes wheels, which is very definitely not cost effective.

Comment: Thank you and yes it is an early 2000's so thank you ill just run this bike into the ground. I have a "newer" shimano sis seven speed that came off my 2017 supercycle phantom 29" snapped the crank on it so just bought this minelli at a yard sale. Ill have a look into something newer and better quality.

Comment: Given 9 speed is a wider cassette than a 7 speed, and that the indexing is all done by the shifter, a 9 speed rear derailler should work fine.  The biggest risk would be running out of limit screw.